# How do I do gtk mouse interaction correctly with Haskell Chart library?

Tags: haskell, charts, gtk

I'm using [this library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.8.2)

As of now I have a point that follows the mouse, but it only kind of works because I assume the window will be 500x500, and the point is never directly behind the mouse because (0,0) on the graph is not (0,0) on the window.

If I could just figure out what the graph origin is relative to the window's coordinates, then I could fix everything, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Renderable seems relevant, such as the "Pick Function" and RectSize, but again I'm not sure how to actually get anything relevant from it. Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend may also be relevant.

Or this may actually be something to solve with gtk? I don't know.

Please help, this has been killing me.

EDIT: [Here's my current code if it helps](http://lpaste.net/358331)